# Redirect When Search Query is an Exact Title in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two post titles in Wordpress:

```
post_title: gröband 
permalink: www.example.com/groband.html

post_title: groband
permalink: www.example.com/groband-2.html
```

I want redirect when search query is "`gröband`" to `www.example.com/groband.html`

if search query is "`groband`" redirect to `www.example.com/groband-2.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your search template in theme editor and add this top

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['s'])){
$url ="";
switch($_GET['s']){
case 'gröband': 
      $url = "http://www.example.com/groband.html"; 
     break;
case 'groband': 
    $url = "www.example.com/groband-2.html";
      break; 
}
if(!empty($url)){
    header("Location: ".$url);
    }
}

?>
```

or

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['s'])){
    switch($_GET['s']){
    case 'gröband': 
         header("Location:http://www.example.com/groband.html"); 
         break;
    case 'groband': 
         header("Location:http://www.example.com/groband-2.html");
         break; 
          }
    }
?>
```

Comment: hi, thanks but they are only sample. I have 100,000+ post title.

Comment: do you save your permalink in your db ?